# start to next without looping

Tags: r

I have two vectors. One is a series of starts or a sequence of id's the other is a guide to the next location from each start.

The key position for my analysis is the first position. I add the corresponding number from the next vector to the position to know were to move next.

```
starts <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
nexts <- c(4,2,1,1,3,5,1,1,3,2,10,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,4,6)
```

What I expect to have is starting at "starts" 1, next tells me to move 4 places, so I end up at starts 1+4, then from starts 5 next tells me to move 3 places, now I am at starts 8, the corresponding next at position 8 is 1, I move to 9, from 9 the next move is 3...

The final goal would be a vector like this one goal <- c(5,8,9,12....). The first vector "starts" might not be needed really if we can make the "jumps" using nexts by just reading the size of the next move at each "landing". like this: from 1 we jump 4, to arrive at 5, from location 5 we jump 3 to position 8 from 8 we jump 1 position to 9....

Comment: Note that you example is not valid R code: make vectors using `c()`, and do not use `next` as a variable name as this is a reserved word. I used the correct syntax in my answer.

Comment: And why do need to do this without looping?

Comment: ...or do you mean without using a `for` loop?

Comment: @Dason, Because the record is in the millions

Comment: Please don't specify that you don't want to do it without looping.  Just tell us that the records are in the millions and you need a quick solution.  If the fastest solution is with a loop then the fastest solution is with a loop...

Comment: And post your desired output to get rid of the ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you did not clearly state a question, I guess what you want is this:

```
starts <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
nexts  <- c(4,2,1,1,3,5,1,1,3,2,10,2,3,4,1,1,1,1,4,6)

i <- 1
while (i %in% starts) {
    s <- starts[i]
    n <- nexts[s] ### <--- correction: not nexts[i]
    i <- s + n
    cat(sprintf("%d + %d -> %d\n", s, n, i))
}

# 1 + 4 -> 5
# 5 + 3 -> 8
# 8 + 1 -> 9
# 9 + 3 -> 12
# 12 + 2 -> 14
# 14 + 4 -> 18
# 18 + 1 -> 19
# 19 + 4 -> 23
```

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, there is a way to do it without a loop; just use a recursive function (which I would not recommend, if you can get the same result with a loop)...

```
recursive.func <- function(start, starts, nexts) {
    next.start <- start + nexts[start]
    if (!next.start %in% starts)
        return(next.start)
    return(c(next.start, recursive.func(next.start, starts, nexts)))
}

# execute like this:
my.start <- starts[1]
recursive.func(my.start, starts, nexts)
```

Comment: BTW, it is easier to define starts as `starts <- 1:20` if it is continuous.

Comment: That would give you a different result, namely: `> starts + nexts
 [1]  5  4  4  5  8 11  8  9 12 12 21 14 16 18 16 17 18 19 23 26` The loop uses the result of the previous combination. BTW, I don't think this could be solved without looping. Even if you use some other function to hide the loop in your code (I am thinking of `lapply` or `Reduce`) most likely there will be looping somewhere on the lower level.

Comment: Still, this does not give the same result (I guess the result produced by my loop example above is intended).

Comment: thanks for the response by the way, because my record is large do you think changing the loop restrictor to while (i < max(starts)) is more efficient than the %in% starts?

Comment: Yes you can! And: I fixed the loop above, ... And: I found another solution. If that answers your question, please check the answer.